# Runtime error while trying to get base fraction

Tags: c++, class, runtime-error

I have a class named `Fraction` and at the outside of the class, function `baseF` to get the base fraction.

```
void Fraction::baseF() {
  int n=num,d=den,i;
  if(n<d) {
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      if(n%i==0 & d%i==0) {n/=i;d/=i;}
  } //end if
  else {
    for(i=0;i<d;i++)
      if(n%i==0 & d%i==0) {n/=i;d/=i;}
  } //end else
  num=n;
  den=d;
}
```

I know that code is not efficient, just trying to get the logic.

Comment: You're dividing by zero rather a lot. There's really no need to test for divisibility with anything less than two.

Comment: What's the difference between the two `for` loops?  (since they are the same, get rid of the `else` clause).

Comment: By the way, you may want to use **logical AND operator &&** instead of *bitwise and operator &*.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The first for loop uses `n` and the second uses `d`.

Comment: You might want this later: `void baseF() {int a=num,b=den; while(b){int t=b; b=a%b; a=t;} num/=a; den/=a;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     if(n%i==0 & d%i==0) {n/=i;d/=i;}
```

In the first iteration of the loop, the value of `i` is zero. Computing `n%i` when `i` is zero is a problem.

Also, `n%i==0 & d%i==0` seems to be a typo. You probably meant `n%i==0 && d%i==0` (bitwise AND vs logical AND)

You may want to use:

```
for(i=1; i<n; i++)
     if(n%i==0 && d%i==0) {n/=i;d/=i;}
```

Make the fix in both the `for` loops.

Comment: Also, the `&` should be replaced by `&&`.